# Rollup + Typescript error when importing files outside baseUrl

Tags: typescript, build, rollup, rollupjs, build-system

I put together a rollup build system that takes a folder of Typescript components exports them as modules.

The build system works perfectly if the component files live within the folder structure:

`src/components/Button`

but the problem arises when I try to import them from outside the `baseUrl` meaning:

`../../javascript/components/Button`

As soon as I try this I get the following errors:

`[!] Error: The keyword 'interface' is reserved`

This is what my `tsconfig` file looks like:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react",
        "module": "es2015",
        "target": "es2017",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "preserveSymlinks": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "paths": {
            "ui": ["../../components"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.tsx"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and my rollup.config

```js
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import less from 'rollup-plugin-less';
import alias from 'rollup-plugin-alias';

const plugins = [
    alias({
        ui: '../../components',
        resolve: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.less']
    }),
    resolve(),
    commonjs({
        // All of our own sources will be ES6 modules, so only node_modules need to be resolved with cjs
        include: 'node_modules/**',
        namedExports: {
            'node_modules/react/index.js': [
                'Component',
                'PropTypes',
                'createElement'
            ],
            'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js': ['isEmpty', 'isString']
        }
    }),
    less({ insert: 'true' }),
    typescript()
];

export default {
    plugins,
    external: ['react'],
    input: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        file: './lib/index.js',
        format: 'cjs'
    }
};
```

Thanks so much in advance!!!

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Whenever I try to import files outside of the project root, it starts throwing errors.

Comment: Still experiencing this

Comment: Neither works with @rollup/plugin-typescript for me

Answer (score 11):

After investigating for a while, I found that `@rollup/plugin-typescript` only transform files inside of project root by default. To override that behavior, you need to specify in the `include` option of the plugin, the globs for the files you plan to use, including the files inside of your project.

```js
import ...


const plugins = [
    /* ... */
    typescript({
      include: [
        // Project files
        './**/*.ts+(|x)',
        // Files from outside of the project
        '../../javascript/**/*.ts+(|x)'
      ]
    })
];

export default {
    /* ... */
};
```

You will also need to do this in your 'tsconfig.json', because the plugin will complain that the external files are not listed in your tsconfig.